# 'ModbusSerialMaster' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating RTU using  NModbus.

Installed NModbus package using following command in Package Manager Console

```
Install-Package NModbus
```

Now I am creating RTU by following line.

```
IModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(Port);
```

But I am getting error

> 'ModbusSerialMaster' is inaccessible due to its protection level

What is the reason and how can I create Modbus RTU to read and wrtite multiple register.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's because `ModbusSerialMaster` is an internal class, as you can see in the [source](https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus/blob/master/NModbus/Device/ModbusSerialMaster.cs).

Browsing around the code, I suspect you want something like this:

```
IModbusFactory factory = new ModbusFactory();
IModbusSerialMaster = factory.CreateMaster(transport);
```

... where `transport` is something that implements `IModbusSerialTransport`.

Alternatively, if you don't need an `IModbusSerialMaster` but an `IModbusRtuTransport` you'd call `CreateRtuTransport`:

```
IModbusFactory factory = new ModbusFactory();
IModbusRtuTransport = factory.CreateRtuTransport(resource);
```

... where `resource` is something that implements `IStreamResource`.

For anything further, I'd probably just clone the source code and browse around it to work out what you can do and what you need.

Comment: Indeed. Was just about to post same answer. See https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus/blob/develop/Samples/Program.cs

Comment: Thanks this was quite helpful. Able to create RTU

Comment: @spender broken link mon